# angular9 generic http calls, using dataservice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The problem:

```
return this.entitesService.getEntities().pipe(
      tap((result: GetEntitiesResponse) => {
        console.log(typeof result);
        console.log('RESULT:', result);
      })
    );
```

There is a type incompatible error in this line:

```
tap((result: GetEntitiesResponse) => {
```

If I will remove the type, or define it as any - then there is no error.
But I want to have types everywhere.

The problem is likely in the dataservice definition.

Current error text message is:

```
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<GetEntitiesResponse>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpEvent<GetEntitiesResponse>, GetEntitiesResponse>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<GetEntitiesResponse>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GetEntitiesResponse>'.
      Type 'HttpEvent<GetEntitiesResponse>' is not assignable to type 'GetEntitiesResponse'.
        Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'GetEntitiesResponse': data, metats(2345)
```

Dataservice:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  protected url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get<T>(endpoint: string, obj: object = null) {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.url + endpoint, this.getHttpParams(obj));
  }

  protected getHttpParams(obj: object) {
    const requestOptions: any = {};
    requestOptions.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    if (obj !== null) {
      requestOptions.params = this.objectToHttpParams(obj);
    }

    return requestOptions;
  }

  protected objectToHttpParams(obj: object): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      params = params.set(key, (obj[key] as unknown) as string);
    }

    return params;
  }
}
```

Is this correct definition to pass the generic type to the angular http?

```
  get<T>(endpoint: string, obj: object = null) {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.url + endpoint, this.getHttpParams(obj));
  }
```

Or there should be another syntax.

And here is the service:

```
export class EntitiesService extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

  getEntities(): Observable<HttpEvent<GetEntitiesResponse>> {
    return this.get<GetEntitiesResponse>('/entities');
  }
}
```

Comment: your function `getEntities()` returns a `Observable<HttpEvent<GetEntitiesResponse>>`. How can this ever be a  `Observable<GetEntitiesResponse>`. :)

Comment: Yes, I made it like that, So I found the root of the problem. It is here:

Comment: get<T>(endpoint: string, obj: object = null): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.url + endpoint, this.getHttpParams(obj));
  }

Comment: If I remove the second parameter - then it works well, but once I return it back - it says incompatible Observable<HttpEvent<T>> and Observable<T>

Comment: But are you sure the `http.get()` does not return a `T` instead of a `HttpEvent<T>`. It only does the latter if you use `observe: 'events'`

Comment: Here is an updated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972063/type-observablehttpeventt-is-not-assignable-to-type-observablet