# Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<T>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The problem is at Line 14

```
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<T>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
  Type 'HttpEvent<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'HttpEvent<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
      Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'HttpSentEvent' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)
```

If I remove the second parameter, `this.getHttpParams(obj)`, then it works well.

But I need to pass the parameters.

How to solve this?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  protected url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get<T>(endpoint: string, obj: object = null): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.url + endpoint, this.getHttpParams(obj)); // Problem is here.
    // If I remove the second parameter: , this.getHttpParams(obj) - then it works good.
    // But I need to pass the parameters. How to solve this?
  }
  protected getHttpParams(obj: object) {
    const requestOptions: any = {};
    requestOptions.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    if (obj !== null) {
      requestOptions.params = this.objectToHttpParams(obj);
    }

    return requestOptions;
  }

  protected objectToHttpParams(obj: object): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      params = params.set(key, (obj[key] as unknown) as string);
    }

    return params;
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it would be happier with a clearer type for the return of `getHttpParams`, e.g. `{headers: HttpHeaders, params?: any}`. Otherwise it seems to think you're changing `observe`.

Comment: Damn, that fixed that. How?

Comment: Because otherwise it doesn't know whether or not you're going to observe the response, so it can't pick between `Observable<T>` and `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`.

Comment: Is it because of this parameter: observe?: 'body';?

Comment: Yes, the `observe` parameter is the one that sets what kind of return type you should expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) has a lot of overloads, some that return `Observable<T>` and others that return `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`. If the return value from `getHttpParams` is `any`, it thinks you'll get the latter.

The minimal fix is therefore to be more specific about what that method could return, for example:

```
protected getHttpParams(obj: object): {headers: HttpHeaders, params?: HttpParams} { ... }
```